# How to match row number to value in dataframe column in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5000 rows and a list with 1032 items (row numbers).
Now I need to match the row number from the list to a value in df.x
I tried it like this but I get an error:

```
max_array = []
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if i == local_max[i]:
        max_array.append(df.x[i])
    else:
        max_array.append(0)

max_array
```

error:

```
index 1032 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1032
```

How can I make it work? preferably vectorized

Answer (score 0):

Try to negate 1 from the length of `df`:

```
max_array = []
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if i == local_max.iloc[i]:
        max_array.append(df.x[i])
    else:
        max_array.append(0)
```

Comment: Still the error. I think the list is too short

Comment: `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: It's weird, I get now : ´list indices must be integers or slices, not Timestamp´. Local_max is definitely not a timestamp

Comment: @stanvooz i think I gotcha, check out my answer now

Answer (score 0):

You could also filter your dataframe. This code only keeps all rows with their index within the list.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

# create random data for testing code
randoms = [random.randint(1, 3000) for i in range(1000)]
max_row_ids = [500, 750]

df = pd.DataFrame(randoms)
maxs = df[df.index.isin(max_row_ids)]
maxs.head()
>>   0
500 358
750 2945
```